# Problem with Java when using Apache Jena Fuseki?

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, jena, ttl

I am trying to install apache jena fuseki but in the process I get the following error, and I don't find the way to solve it.

```
PS C:\apache-jena-fuseki-5.0.0-rc1> .\fuseki-server --update --mem /ds
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jena/fuseki/cmd/FusekiCmd has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I have seen that there are some post regarding a similar error, but I am unable to make it work. I tried updating Java and creating the JAVA_HOME variable, but none of that made any change. I hope someone can help me solve it!! :)

Comment: Hi Trime, this question does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines and is likely to get closed soon for several reasons, including asking multiple questions in a single post and asking for recommendations for resources. Try [taking the SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking a question that is appropriate for this website. Good luck!

Comment: You can load the Turtle file into some local triple store, e.g. use Apache Jena from CLI - or simply do the SPARQL query without loading it into a triple store. With Python you can use rdflib. Understanding the data can be done by watching at the provided OWL file as well as the image, both contained in the Tarball which you download. The rest is then learning basic SPARQL queries and then getting more specific.

Comment: For better help, you should start with loading the data and trying SPARQL. Then ask specific questions here, people will answer them carefully

Comment: `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` means the JVM is an earlier version of Java from the one which is the target of the build. Jena 5.0.0 requires Java17. Jena4 required Java11.

Comment: You're trying to run something compiled for Java 17 (class version 61) on Java 8 (max supported class version 52). In any case, duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)